# How to disable the welcoming screen for when PC wakes up

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

Windows 7 (x64) has a blue welcome screen (blue grass picture) which shows my user icon in the center. After PC sleeps and wakes up, this screen is shown. How do I skip it, and not have to press the user icon?

Comment: Same screen- on WIN+L key press is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the control panel, power options. Click the link "require a password on wakeup".

[image: require a password on wakeup]

Click the "change settings" link, select "don't require a password" and lastly "save changes".

[image: require a password on wakeup]

You can still press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> before putting the computer to sleep, if you actually want to see the login screen when it wakes up. This would protect you if you have a password set.

Comment: It sounds like the OP doesn't even have a password on his account, so pressing Win-L doesn't offer any protection. It just forces the mentioned blue screen to appear.

Comment: You would still get the login screen, which means a single click to get back to the desktop. The OP wanted to get immediately to the desktop without that inconvenience.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just commenting on your _"if you actually want it to be protected"_ part. Since he doesn't have a password, pressing Win-L doesn't offer any protection except hiding the screen. But yea, if he adds a password but disables requiring a password, then pressing Win-L will offer protection without forcing him to enter password every time he resumes the computer from sleep.

Comment: Fair enough. I've edited the answer to reflect this.